# unable to define dynamic ng-model for Multiselect checkboxes with angular-Selectize

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, selectize.js

I am trying to achieve Multiselect dropdown with checkboxes by using selectiz.js. I am able to customize my dropdown using render option in selectize. However if i click one of the checkboxes it will click all the others checkboxes which is not desired. I understand that this is because all the options are binded to one ng-model. I tried to make it dynamic but everything seems to fail Under selectize render options. I will really appreciate if some one can help me with this issue. I have tried to put the simplest version here. Also please note I amusing Icheck plugin for checkboxes.

```
<html ng-app="checkBoxes">

<head>


<body ng-controller="selectizeDropdownCtrl">

  <h2 class="header">Multi Selelct</h2>
  <input id="dropdown" config="assigneeConfig" options="assigneesOptions" position="bottom" ng-model="model" selectize/>

</body>
```

```
"use strict";
 angular.module('checkBoxes')
.controller('selectizeDropdownCtrl',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $compile) {

        //================================================================
        // Initialize Data
        //================================================================

        $scope.assigneesOptions = [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Mercury, Freddie"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Morty, Rick"
            }
        ];



    $scope.assigneeConfig = {
            autoBind: true,
            valueField: 'id',
            labelField: 'name',
            maxItems: null,
            placeholder: 'Select...',
            render: {
                option: function (item, escape) {

                    var html= '<div class="option">' +
                        '<div class="uk-input-group">'+
                   '<span class="uk-input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" ng-model= "checkboxesModel"  icheck/></span>'+
                   ' <span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>'++
                         '</div>';
                    return $compile(html)($scope)
                }
            },




        };


    });
```